# How to download report pbix file?

Tags: powerbi

I have a report pointing to a shared dataset. I want to edit the visualizations but I have lost the pbix file. The report exists on the power bi service.

However, there is no option to download the report pbix file. How can I download the report pbix file?

Answer (score 0):

don't you see something like this?
[image]

Comment: No, I am the workspace Admin yet I cannot see this. Is there any tenant level settings

Comment: can you add screenshot of your workspace or your http://powerbi.microsoft.com/

Comment: There is a tenant setting in the export and sharing setting allowing the turn off/on of report downloading, check to see if that is enabled https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-portal#workspace-settings